# What determines the quality of items in vending machines?

Tags: borderlands-2

What are the factors that determine the quality of items you find in vending machines? Does your current level come in to it, or is it just determined by location (i.e. the further you are away from the starting point the better the items)?

Just wondering if it's worth looking through the items in the earlier vending machines, or if that's just a waste of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's the same as Borderlands 1: vending machines level to the area when you first enter it, and stay around that level when you go back to them.

Certain missions re-level certain areas, so then the vending machines and enemies rank to your current level.

On top of that the vending machines before some bosses appear to be slightly higher level too.

Comment: Sanctuary's vending machines appear to scale up to level or at least the latest story mission. They don't scale past the end of the game though

Comment: @BenBrocka - I don't think all of them do; I went back to the frozen area for a quest I missed near the start and all the gear was levelled to that quest. Possibly an area levels up once you've cleared all the quests AND progressed a story milestone?

Comment: Yeah, stuff seems to level to quests, but Sanctuary seems to always be up to date. It might just be story milestones for Sanctuary though